# How to use a org-capture template expansion several times in a captured note

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I am trying to create a org-capture template that re-uses some text given with the `‘%^{PROMPT}’` expansion along several points of the created note.

I have looked in [org-mode Template-expansion doc](https://orgmode.org/manual/Template-expansion.html#Template-expansion) and in Stack Overflow for such an option without success.

```lisp
("J" "Jobs" entry (file+headline "~/org/NOTES.org" "Jobs") ; jobs
"* TODO %^{Name of Job}\nSCHEDULED: %(org-insert-time-stamp (org-read-date nil t \"+0d\"))\n 
- [[%x][Advert]] \n 
- Coverletter pdf \n 
- [[file:~/Documents/Personal/CV/CV.tex][CV]] [[file:~/Documents/Personal/CV/CV.pdf][pdf]] \n 
- [[shell:mkdir -p ~/Documents/Personal/$(date +%Y%M_%^{Name of Job})][makedir]]")
```

The above example prompts me for `"Name of Job"` (see 2nd and last line) in two separate instances. I would like to re-use the information that I have given to fill the template automatically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the page you linked, it says you can reuse a prompt value with `%\1`. Instead of `%^{Name of Job}` twice, use `%\\1` for the second occurrence in your template. You'll need the extra `\` because it's inside a string and needs to be escaped.

```
("J" "Jobs" entry (file+headline "~/org/NOTES.org" "Jobs") ; jobs
"* TODO %^{Name of Job}\nSCHEDULED: %(org-insert-time-stamp (org-read-date nil t \"+0d\"))\n 
- [[%x][Advert]] \n 
- Coverletter pdf \n 
- [[file:~/Documents/Personal/CV/CV.tex][CV]] [[file:~/Documents/Personal/CV/CV.pdf][pdf]] \n 
- [[shell:mkdir -p ~/Documents/Personal/$(date +%Y%M_%\\1)][makedir]]")
```

Comment: There are so many options that I've missed that one. Thank you very much for pointing it out, and the detail of the \.

Comment: Escaping the back slash inside a string. THANK YOU.